# Data structure for finding pairs of matrices under constraint

Tags: performance-tuning, data-structures

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**

Given three positive integers `k, n1, n2`, I have a list of matrices

```
matrices = Tuples[Range[0,k], {n1,n2}]
```

Since `Length[matrices]` = $(k+1)^{n1 \cdot n2}$ grows pretty quickly, we can consider `k = 2`, `n1 = 2`, `n2 = 3` here.

We can compute the row- and column sums of the matrices:

```
rowsums = Total[matrices, {2}];
colsums = Total[matrices, {3}];
```

Now we are given two more non-negative integers `p1, p2`, e.g. `p1 = 0, p2 = 1`. I want to find all pairs of matrices `{m1, m2}` from `matrices` that satisfy the following constraints:

1. The row sums of `m1 - m2` are sorted; `Sort[Total[m1-m2, {2}]] == Total[m1 - m2, {2}]`.
2. The smallest row sum is greater or equal to `-p1`.
3. The column sums of `m1 - m2` are sorted.
4. The smallest column sum is greater or equal to `-p2`.

Notice in particular that `m1 = m2` satisfies the constraints.

Looping through all possible pairs and checking whether or not they satisfy the constrains quickly becomes **very** time consuming. My idea to solve this without looping through all the pairs, is to put `matrices` into some type of data structure that would let me find valid `m1` for a given `m2`.

**QUESTION**: How can we make a data structure suited for this in *Mathematica*?

My attempt is the following:

```
tree[_][__] = {};
Do[

 Do[
  treeval = Take[colsums[[ind]], i];
  tree[i][treeval] = Union[tree[i][treeval], {colsums[[ind, i + 1]]}]
  , {i, n1 - 1}
  ];
 treeval = colsums[[ind]];
 tree[n1][treeval] = Union[tree[n1][treeval], {rowsums[[ind, 1]]}];
 Do[
  treeval = Take[rowsums[[ind]], j];
  tree[n1 + j][colsums[[ind]], treeval] = 
   Union[tree[n1 + j][colsums[[ind]], treeval], {rowsums[[ind, j + 1]]}]
  , {j, n2 - 1}
  ];

 , {ind, Length[matrices]}
 ];
```

This works in the following way: matrices are sorted first on their colsums, then on their rowsums. `tree[ind][colsumSubset]` returns a list of possible values of the `ind + 1`th colsum, given that the `ind` first colsums is given by `colsumSubset`. If the returned list is empty, that means no such matrix exists in `matrices`. If all colsums have been specified, the next form is `tree[n1 + ind - 1][colsums, rowsumSubset]`. But I'm note sure this type of construction is anywhere close to ideal for this problem...

Any insights much appreciated!